# How to load image and text of that image paralelly into a div using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Actually,I'm able to load 3 images(open,new&save icons) into a div using angularjs.Now,I'm trying to place the related text of those images into the same div just below those 3 images.

Like,"open" text should be written just below "open" image.Simialrly,for the remaining images too.How can I achieve this?

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

My js code:

```
angular.module('Sample', []).controller('Home', function($scope) {

    $scope.imageSources = [];
    $scope.imageSources.push('images/open.png');
    $scope.imageSources.push('images/new.jpg');
    $scope.imageSources.push('images/save.png');

});
```

My html code:

```
<div style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <img width=40 height=50 style="margin-left: 12px;"
                        ng-repeat="imageSource in imageSources track by $index"
                        ng-src="{{imageSource}}"> </img>
                </div>
```

Comment: Instead of an array of strings, use an array of objects, where each object contains a field for the path of the image, and a field for its text.

Comment: do you mean you want to print `'images/open.png'`, or you want to print some other text that you haven't shown in your sample?

Comment: Try using what i have done in my answer.And Do not perform push call multiple time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work but is not the right way to do it.
I leave the styling up to you.

View:

```
  <div style="margin-top: 15px;" ng-repeat="imageSource in imageSources">
    <img width=40 height=50 style="margin-left: 12px;" ng-src="{{imageSource}}" />
    <br>
    <span style="margin-left: 12px;">{{getFilenameFromPath(imageSource)}}</span>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.imageSources = [];
  $scope.imageSources.push('images/open.png');
  $scope.imageSources.push('images/new.jpg');
  $scope.imageSources.push('images/save.png');


  $scope.getFilenameFromPath = function(filename) {
    return filename.split("/")[1].split(".")[0];
  }
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2hd9x4m/).

---

The right way as it has been mentioned in the contents, is to have a collection of object and each objects should have a `name` and a `src` property. In your case you should do:

```
$scope.imageSources = [];
  $scope.imageSources.push({
    name:"open",
    src: "images/open.png"
  });
  $scope.imageSources.push({
    name:"new",
    src: "images/new.png"
  });
  $scope.imageSources.push({
    name:"save",
    src: "images/save.png"
  });
```

So you will end up with this collection:

```
[
  {
    "name": "open",
    "src": "images/open.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "new",
    "src": "images/new.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "save",
    "src": "images/save.png"
  }
]
```

Here is an [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j84k559j/).

Comment: I want to get all the images aligned horizontally instead of vertical

Comment: @GangiguntaDivya that is another request... But anyway, here is an example of that http://jsfiddle.net/2n58Ler6/

Comment: Can I load the image and text beside that image and similar for 5 more images in a horizontal manner